# Update Stripe Credit Card with Coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, coffeescript, stripe-payments

I finally figured out how to implement Stripes Monthly Billing using this [tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer)

Currently my Submit Button for both my #new_subscription form and edit form creates and sends credit card data to Stripe.

**But for some reason I keep getting this error when I update the Credit Card**

```
can't convert Symbol into String
app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:38:in `update'
```

**Question: Is this error due to the coffeescript, or is my update_card method in my model causing this problem?**

EDIT FORM

```
<%= form_for @subscription, :html => { :id => "update_card" } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

  <h4>Change Credit Card</h4>

   <div class="field">
     <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
     <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
     <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
     <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
     <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
     <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
   </div>

   <%= f.submit "Change Credit Card", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

JS.COFFEE

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()
  changecard.setupForm()

###That part is working great in the coffee script.

subscription =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_subscription').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        subscription.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      {number: $('#card_number').val(),
      cvc: $('#card_code').val(),
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val(),
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()}

    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#subscription_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_subscription')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)

###This is the Coffee for my Edit Form..
changecard =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#update_card').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        changecard.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      {number: $('#card_number').val(),
      cvc: $('#card_code').val(),
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val(),
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()}

     Stripe.createToken(card, changecard.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#subscription_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#update_card')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

MODEL

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :plan_id, :user_id, :email, :stripe_customer_token, :last_4_digits,
              :card_token, :card_name, :exp_month, :exp_year, :stripe_card_token

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def update_card(attrs)
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_token)
    customer.email = "myemail@gmail.com"
    customer.description = "Subscription"

    ###This is being used for the credit card data
    customer.card = attrs[:stripe_card_token]
    customer.save

  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e 
    logger.error "Stripe Error: " + e.message 
    errors.add :base, "#{e.message}." 
    false
  end
```

CONTROLLER

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @subscription = current_user.subscription

    ### I use the method update_card to update the customer's card
    @subscription.update_card(params[:subscription])  

     if @subscription.update_card
      redirect_to edit_subscription_path, 
      flash[:success] = 'Credit Card was Succesfully Updated.' 
    else
      flash.alert = 'Unable to update card.'
      render :edit 
    end
  end
```

Reference: [Stripe Reference for Ruby](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer)

LOGS

```
Started PUT "/subscriptions/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-30 16:23:20 -0800
Processing by SubscriptionsController#update as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ehyUD17CbH7MMOe98s+Kqkh+wGghntWkG4OpoqbnQaA=", 
"subscription"=>{"plan_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", 
"stripe_card_token"=>"tok_103PJj26f8kAprmwvAtoZFRq"}, "id"=>"5"}

User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'xEeu1X6IK9gUAsna9b6Mow' 

LIMIT 1
Subscription Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "subscriptions".* 
FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1

Redirected to 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1283ms

TypeError (can't convert Symbol into String):
app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:38:in `update'
```

Comment: Seems like we are working on the same thing, as some of your posts have been related to my app. Can you send me a email or I can have yours as I would like to discuss privately about stripe. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `update_card` with `params` as the argument:

```
@subscription.update_card(params)
```

and `update_card` is expecting `:stripe_card_token` in `params`:

```
def update_card(params)
  #...
  customer.card = params[:stripe_card_token]
```

but there is no `params[:stripe_card_token]`, the token is in `params[:subscription][:stripe_card_token]`:

```
Parameters: {
  ...
  "subscription"=>{ ... "stripe_card_token"=>"tok_103PCo26f8kAprmwHCPjZ6T5"}, 
}
```

That `params` structure also matches your form's structure:

```
<%= form_for @subscription, :html => { :id => "update_card" } do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>
```

The `form_for @subscription` will set up the form to use `subscription[X]` for field `X` so that `hidden_field` will have `name="subscription[stripe_card_token]"` in the HTML and that translates to `params[:subscription][:stripe_card_token]` in the controller.

Perhaps you mean to say:

```
@subscription.update_card(params[:subscription])
```

You also have a stray call to `@subscription.update_card` without any arguments. Your whole controller method should probably look more like this:

```
def update
  @subscription = current_user.subscription
  if @subscription.update_card(params[:subscription])
    redirect_to edit_subscription_path, :success => 'Updated Card.' 
  else
    flash.alert = 'Unable to update card.'
    render :edit 
  end
end
```

Comment: ic, so then would my update_card method would now have customer.card = params[:subscription] too? or does that stay the same?

Comment: `params` inside `update_card` would already be the right chunk of the controller's `params`. I'd recommend `def update_card(attrs)` to avoid getting the names confused.

Comment: Okay I have updated the code above. It finally works and it passes the credit card data to stripe. But on my end I am getting this error. Can't convert Symbol into String

Comment: I don't see 38 lines in the SubscriptionsController code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think its typo, you have written 'subscription.processCard()' instead of 'changecard.processCard()'

```
changecard =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#update_card').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        changecard.processCard()
        false
      else
        true
```

Comment: yea i had thought of that, i actually fixed it but i get the same results. :/